# Specify an alternative node (IP:Port) for Drizzle, if there is no MetaMask or Web3-enabled browser

Tags: web3js, drizzle

Drizzle will automatically use the injected Web3 object. But if there is now Web3 object, Drizzle will try to connect to ws://127.0.0.1:8545'.

How to configure Drizzle to connect to Infura.io for example?

Answer (score 0):

A custom provider or a fallback url could be provided to Drizzle inside the `opitons` object (https://truffleframework.com/docs/drizzle/reference/drizzle-options).

Bellow is an example of specifying Infura main-net as a fallback url:

```
var options = {
  contracts: [],
  web3: {
    fallback: {
      type: 'ws',
      url: "wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws"
    }
  }
};

drizzle = new Drizzle(options);
```

Note: Current Drizzle version depend on Web3 v1.0.0-beta35 that has issues connecting to Infura (https://github.com/trufflesuite/drizzle/issues/186). To connect the current verison of Drizzle you can download the code, change the Web3 version to be 1.0.0-beta36 or above. Then build and use the new Drizzle js file.